# Pandas dataframe date not able to convert to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert INSERTEDDT column to datetime format

Tried Below but didn't work :

```
df["INSERTEDDT"]= pd.to_datetime(df["INSERTEDDT"]) 
df['INSERTEDDT']= pd.to_datetime(df['INSERTEDDT']) 
df['INSERTEDDT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['INSERTEDDT'], errors='coerce')
```

**Note**: Type of `INSERTEDDT` is object

```
>Error:
ParserError: Unknown string format: 08-FEB-19 10.13.52.081105000 AM
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data, something like `df.head(5)`

Comment: Try `pd.to_datetime(df['INSERTEDDT'],format='%d-%b-%y %H.%M.%S.%f %p')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the below format:

```
'%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p'
```

---

```
df["INSERTEDDT"]= pd.to_datetime(df["INSERTEDDT"],format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p')
```

---

Example with the string in your error message:

```
s = "08-FEB-19 10.13.52.081105000 PM"
s1 = "08-FEB-19 10.13.52.081105000 AM"
ser = pd.Series([s,s1])
print(pd.to_datetime(ser,format='%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p' ))

0   2019-02-08 22:13:52.081105
1   2019-02-08 10:13:52.081105
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Actually `pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format="%d-%b-%y %I.%M.%S.%f %p")` because `%H` is for 24 hour format.

Comment: @sotmot just realized that and edited my answer, thanks for your comment :)